# Check if data is already inserted in database in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

I'm doing an ajax call to save data.Now the issue is that user might unknowingly submit the same data twice and it will become duplicate. Is there any shortcut or validation for abandoning the user from submitting or saving the same data twice?

Also please note that created_at,updated_at will not be same when the user submits the form for the second time. Also the only thing that can be unique in my table is ID :) .

If I have 10 form fields and until and Unless all the 10 fields of my form are same the validator will not reject the data.

Comment: It's not clear enough, you should show some code and explain in details what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an attribute like 'title' and check if it's uniq for that user :

```
class SomeModel < AR
  validates_uniqueness_of :title, :scope => [:user_id]
end
```

Comment: Uniqueness is not a solution as there might be case where same values can be inserted twice and in my case the only thing that could be unique is ID :) .One possible solution could be catching or may be find that data before saving it. I'm bit reluctant to use "Find" as  finding all the fields will be time consuming and it might slowdown my application and also the code will become lenthy.

Comment: thats what validates_uniqueness is actually doing (but if you scope it to more attributes the likelihood the same ones will appear should make it acceptable. eg: one user can't post twice the same title but the same title can appear from different users....

Comment: What I mean is that I have 10 form fields and until and Unless all the 10 fields of my form are same the validator will not reject the data.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think there's a reasonable solution of this problem on the server side.
Try a simple magic of javascript [disable_with](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-submit_tag).